# Related questions list is missing text

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

The related questions list on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225603/c-accessing-object-on-heap-after-end-of-pointer-scope) seems to be broken.

[image: Image with broken Related list]

At least one other user can reproduce the issue.
Looking at the HTML code it seems that the text is just not there:

```
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/252585?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    4
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/270427?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270427/activator-getobject-marshalbyrefobject?rq=1">Activator.GetObject
  - MarshalByRefObject</a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https%20%3Cdiv%20class="></a><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/252585?rq=1" title=
  "Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    4
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/270427?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270427/activator-getobject-marshalbyrefobject?rq=1">Activator.GetObject
  - MarshalByRefObject</a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/276366?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/289064?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289064/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/307898?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307898/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/308010?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    2
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/312038?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    39
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312038/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/322468?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    9
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322468/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/335060?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    2
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335060/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/354086?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    0
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354086/?rq=1"></a>
</div>://stackoverflow.com/q/276366?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)"&gt;
<div class="answer-votes default">
  1
</div><a class="question-hyperlink" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/?rq=1"></a>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/289064?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289064/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/307898?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    1
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307898/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/308010?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    2
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/312038?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    39
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312038/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/322468?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    9
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322468/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/335060?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    2
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335060/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
<div class="spacer js-gps-track">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/354086?rq=1" title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">
  <div class="answer-votes default">
    0
  </div></a><a class="question-hyperlink" href=
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354086/?rq=1"></a>
</div>
```

<s>Only that one page is affected; other pages don't show that issue for me.</s>

The comments pointed out more such questions:

[Conversion of times in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230320/conversion-of-times-in-c) on SO and
[I want to collect a lot of rep. Is there a problem with it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300886/164356) on Meta.SE, so this seems to be a network-wide issue.

Comment: I was also able to duplicate this issue. Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE so it doesn't appear to be browser specific. (FWIW, I wasn't logged in on IE either.) Windows machine. It looks like the issue could be that the links are pointing to **answers** instead of **questions**. The only link with a title points to the question properly instead of including an anchor to a specific answer.

Comment: I can reproduce as well when logged in or logged out.

Comment: The links use the /question route but do point to answers. This is definitely a backend issue as the source file being served does not have text in the anchor elements

Comment: Can reproduce it here also, and for me the links are posting to aswers, just like BSMP said. They all link to the first answer. Interesting stuff: the first link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/?rq=1, but actually links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307901/

Comment: Don't worry, probably a PHP module.

Comment: I noticed that too, and I posted a question about it on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300893/349538

Comment: I can reproduce it in FF on OSX

Comment: Able to reproduce on Chrome and Safari and Opera on macOS and "full site" on Safari on iOS for SO, but not reproducible for the meta.SE post.

Comment: @paper1111 - try again.

Comment: Details of the fix are here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300915/140505

Comment: I'm still able to reproduce in the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230320/conversion-of-times-in-c). Even overriding FF cache. Not sure if we have an ISP cache?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Same for me, reloading fixes all related questions lists except for that question.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: @nwp yes! It is.